# Keras get_weights and set_weights during training: "Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function"

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using Tensorflow2/Keras I want to modify the weights of a model component during training, according to some update rule. For this I used `get_weights()` and `set_weights()` method. I've tried to implement this as follows:

```
class CAD_model(keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(self, online_encoder, target_encoder, predictor, **kwargs):
        super(CAD_model, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.online_encoder = online_encoder
        self.target_encoder = target_encoder
        self.predictor = predictor
        
    def call(self, x):
        z = self.target_encoder(x)
        return z
    
    def compile(self, optimizer):
        super(CAD_model, self).compile()
        self.opt = optimizer
    
    def compute_loss(self, x1, x2):
        
        online_encoder = self.online_encoder
        target_encoder = self.target_encoder
        
        y = online_encoder(x1)
        z1 = self.predictor(y)
        # Stop gradient
        z2 = tf.stop_gradient(target_encoder(x2))        
        loss = tf.reduce_mean((z1 - z2)**2)
        return loss
    
    def update_ema(self, decay=0.999):
        online_vars = self.online_encoder.get_weights()
        target_vars = self.target_encoder.get_weights()
        ema_vars = [decay * var1 + (1 - decay) * var2 for var1, var2 in zip(target_vars, online_vars)]
        self.target_encoder.set_weights(ema_vars)

    def train_step(self, data):
        
        x1, x2 = data
            
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self.compute_loss(x1, x2)        
        
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        
        self.update_ema()
        
        return {
            "loss": loss,
        }
```

When running `CAD_model.fit` I get:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function.
```

Which pertains to the `get_weights` and `set_weights` operations. How can properly extract and assign weights such that the operation is performed within the graph?

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround** : move  **`train_step`** function out of your model class.

The following example may help you

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class seq_model(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")
        self.dense2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")
        self.classifier = layers.Dense(784, activation="softmax", name="predictions")
        self.mse_loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        outputs = self.classifier(x)
        return outputs

    def compile(self, optimizer):
        super().compile()
        self.opt = optimizer
        return self

    def train_step(self, data):
        x_batch_train = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            reconstructed = self(x_batch_train)
            loss = self.mse_loss_fn(x_batch_train, reconstructed)
            loss += sum(self.losses)

        grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

        # This line would give error:
        # RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function.
        # online_vars = self.dense1.get_weights()
        # print(online_vars)

        return {
            "loss": loss,
        }


model = seq_model().compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3))


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
)


# workaround

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
mse_loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

loss_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train)
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)

epochs = 2

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Start of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    for step, x_batch_train in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            reconstructed = model(x_batch_train)
            loss = mse_loss_fn(x_batch_train, reconstructed)
            loss += sum(model.losses)  # Add KLD regularization loss

        grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
        # this line runs well
        online_vars = model.dense1.get_weights()
        print(online_vars)

        loss_metric(loss)

        if step % 100 == 0:
            print("step %d: mean loss = %.4f" % (step, loss_metric.result()))
```